# Get screenshots of other running apps on android

Tags: android, process, screenshot

On Android I can get list of running applications by executing getRunningAppProcesses on activity manager:

```
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

But I want something more, when I open system task manager, there are screenshots of running applications, like on
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akv8X.png)
Can I get those screenshots in my own application? How to get image representing contents of given window?

Endriu

Comment: Do you need to see the screenshots inside of your app? Or you want to just make a screenshots of other app in your device?

Comment: I want to see them inside of my app.

Answer (score 0):

take screenshot without needs root access:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void takeScreenshot(Context context, String fileFullPath)
    {
        if(fileFullPath == ""){
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            String fileName = format.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())) + ".png";
            fileFullPath = "/data/local/tmp/" + fileName;
        }

        if(ShellUtils.checkRootPermission()){
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
                ShellUtils.execCommand("/system/bin/screencap -p "+ fileFullPath,true);
            }
        }
        else {
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
                wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                mDisplay = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
                mDisplayMatrix = new Matrix();
                mDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                // We need to orient the screenshot correctly (and the Surface api seems to take screenshots
                // only in the natural orientation of the device :!)
                mDisplay.getRealMetrics(mDisplayMetrics);
                float[] dims =
                {
                        mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels, mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels
                };
                float degrees = getDegreesForRotation(mDisplay.getRotation());
                boolean requiresRotation = (degrees > 0);
                if (requiresRotation){
                    // Get the dimensions of the device in its native orientation
                    mDisplayMatrix.reset();
                    mDisplayMatrix.preRotate(-degrees);
                    mDisplayMatrix.mapPoints(dims);
                    dims[0] = Math.abs(dims[0]);
                    dims[1] = Math.abs(dims[1]);
                }

                Bitmap mScreenBitmap = screenShot((int) dims[0], (int) dims[1]);
                if (requiresRotation)   {
                    // Rotate the screenshot to the current orientation
                    Bitmap ss = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels, mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels,
                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas c = new Canvas(ss);
                    c.translate(ss.getWidth() / 2, ss.getHeight() / 2);
                    c.rotate(degrees);
                    c.translate(-dims[0] / 2, -dims[1] / 2);
                    c.drawBitmap(mScreenBitmap, 0, 0, null);
                    c.setBitmap(null);
                    mScreenBitmap = ss;
                    if (ss != null && !ss.isRecycled()) {
                        ss.recycle();
                    }
                }

                // If we couldn't take the screenshot, notify the user
                if (mScreenBitmap == null){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "screen shot fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // Optimizations
                mScreenBitmap.setHasAlpha(false);
                mScreenBitmap.prepareToDraw();

                saveBitmap2file(context, mScreenBitmap, fileFullPath);  // save image file
            }
        }

    }
```

Source: [ScreentShotUtil.java](https://github.com/Android-ScreenShot/AndroidScreenShotService/blob/master/ScreentShotUtil.java)

Comment: This is not exactly what I meant. I don't want to have screenshot of current screen, I have screenshots/previews of minimized applications, exactly as on attached image (built in task manager somehow can get them).

Answer (score 0):

`SystemServicesProxy` class has [getThumbnail](https://worthdoingbadly.com/androidrecents/) method to get required task thumbnail through its id. Before that you need to get running apps ids using `getRecentTasks`. You can read more about it [here](https://worthdoingbadly.com/androidrecents/).