# screen capture of other running apps (android)

Tags: android, screenshot, screen-capture

My aim is to build a screen sharing (or remote viewing) application for android just like there is VNC for desktop. For this purpose i need to take screenshots and then relay them over the network to the target. I browsed through the solutions offered on a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994007/get-screenshots-of-other-running-apps-on-android) on stack overflow.

Having a slight knowledge of android (i am a beginner), I noticed that all the answers used the View object to get the screenshot. Now, if im not wrong, this means that they are taking a screenshot of their own app and not other running apps. And to take a screenshot of other running apps I would have to run as a background service which does not have access to the View object.

I found another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994007/get-screenshots-of-other-running-apps-on-android) but it was not useful. So I want to know if it is possible to take a screenshot of other apps in android. Im beginning to think that it is not. Maybe it would be a security risk? Please correct me if im wrong. Im just a beginner at this. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10482368/4706693  Have a look at the second part of his answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it